Bad Image message with error code 0xc0000428. What does this mean?
I have a project running at hundreds of customers. The EXE uses WebView2 as an evergreen installation. It runs in 99.9% of all installations without problems.
One customer has an older version (dated 2022) now has problems. The facts:

Fresh installation for Windows 11 in a domain.
All service packs installed.
Program is launched from a network drive.

The customer gets this error message (in German):

WebView2Loader.dll is either not designed to run on Windows or it
contains an error. Try installing the program again using the original
installation media or contact your system administrator or the
software vendor for support. Error status 0xc0000428.

I rechecked the WebView2Loader.dll. The DLL is signed. The signature is correct.
In the MSDN I read
0xC0000428 STATUS_INVALID_IMAGE_HASH
The hash for image %hs cannot be found in the system catalogs. The image is likely corrupt or the victim of tampering.
I could fix the problem in using a more current WebView2Loader.dll. Currently the problem vanishes.
I want to know what this error really means? The binary is valid and signed and orginal.
Some details to the file that failes:
WebView2Loader.dll size 109472 bytes dated 2022-01-05 10:44. Version 1.0.1072.54.

I have had this issue, too. On the Client was the software "Malewarebytes" installed. It was running together with the Microsoft Defender. In my opinion not a good solution. I uninstalled Malewarebytes and after that the error with the WebView2Loader.dll 0xC0000428 was solved.

I can'ht agree to that. All machines at the customer used the same configuration. This Software wasn't in use. There was no additional anti-virus software installed.

I actually stumbled across this while working on an issue with a brand new Windows 11 install. It did end up being AV related. I didn't think it was SentinelOne at first because we have other clients using CCH Fixed Assets with Windows 11 and S1, but it appears that when the application was installed with S1 enabled it breaks the install.
After I removed S1 completely, it still wouldn't launch, so i reinstalled and confirmed it's working now.
May help whoever stumbles across this in the future.
